# Question about chord placement in "Vienna" by Billy Joel

Tags: chord-theory

I'm doing an analysis of "Vienna" by Billy Joel to help improve my music theory, and I am confused about the presence of the A♭ Major chord in the song's verses. The song is in the key of B♭, so naturally A♭ Major would not be a diatonic chord, but I can't seem to find its purpose... It resolves to an E♭ Major chord, so I'm wondering if it acts as a secondary dominant or something else?

Comment: As @Tim says this is used in an “awful lot of songs”. Here is a great albeit pretty long article about this chord and it’s uses. If nothing else it will show how prolific this chord has been in pop music since the 50’s. http://www.icce.rug.nl/~soundscapes/VOLUME22/Magnificent_flat-seventh.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ♭VII chord is used in an awful lot of songs, it's almost become the 'next on the list after diatonics'.

Some say it's a *borrowed* chord, taken from the parallel minor key. Others say that it works as a sort of dominant chord to the tonic. Yet others say it's V/?, a secondary dominant, but it doesn't lead to ♭III here. (Not that secondary dominants *have* to lead to their own I). Some say it's a sort of reverse V/V - a IV/IV. The rest of us just say 'well, it works, and that's good enough'.

Comment: And I say:  ♭ VII - V7 is just a substitution for  ii-V7 : C,E♭  ( the 3rd and 5th of A♭  maj.) - are shared tones with Cm.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its function is secondary dominate.

Comment: Could you expound upon this a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Ab would be a dominant for Db, so no go on secondary dominant.  Ab is a secondary SUBDOMINANT for Eb, or part of a mixolydian chord prog. (bVII)

Comment: Surprising, possibly, but *secondary dominants* don't *have* to resolve directly to the chord a fourth above. They only have to be a chromatic dominant as in non-diatonic.

Comment: From the standpoint of classical harmony they have to resolve, otherwise the analysis is completely pointless.  Moreover, I could argue that Ab in a key of Bb is a tritone sub for III... but that would be a stretch. :)  It's nothing more but a major with flat VII.  It's quite common in pop music.